# How to download images from local html file?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I have a some simple html pages Test.html, test2.html, test3.html. This pages have some links to images:

```
<img src="http://site.org/path/to/file/6c7f2.jpeg"/>
```

How download all images from this pages automatically, put near the html files and change links in html pages to local images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command `$ wget -F -i <html_file>`

This will download every link contained in your `<html_file>` and put them in the current directory. I recommend you to read the manual of wget (`$ man wget`) under the OPTIONS section from where i extracted the folowing:

> -i file
>   --input-file=file
>
> ```
>   Read URLs from a local or external file.  If - is specified as file, URLs are
> read from the standard input.  (Use ./- to read from a file literally named -.)
>
>   If this function is used, no URLs need be present on the command line.  If
> there are URLs both on the command line and in an input file, those on the
> command lines will be the first ones to be retrieved.  If --force-html is not
> specified, then file should consist of a series of URLs, one per line.
>
>   However, if you specify --force-html, the document will be regarded as html.
> In that case you may have problems with relative links, which you can solve
> either by adding "<base href="url">" to the documents or by specifying
> --base=url on the command line.
>
>   If the file is an external one, the document will be automatically treated as
> html if the Content-Type matches text/html. Furthermore,the file's location
> will be implicitly used as base href if none was specified.
> ```

and the option:

> -F
>   --force-html
>
> ```
>   When input is read from a file, force it to be treated as an HTML file.
> This enables you to retrieve relative links from existing HTML files on
> your local disk, by adding "<base href="url">" to HTML, or using the
> --base command-line option.
> ```

Also, I recommend you to read the `--output-file` option from the man page.

This will only handle the download stuff... to make automatic changes on your html file i think you need other tools that shellscripting either does not provide or, if it does, are very complicated to use. I recommend doing a script in python that uses the mentioned command to the downloading stuff, and some python specialized library to process (parse) the file, and make the convenient changes.

Good luck!!!

Comment: Thank You! Very helpful. Plan to modify html by sed and other utilities like sed, basename and other!

Comment: wow! `sed` is a very powerfull tool, but quite complicated to use... I haven't mastered it yet hehehe... good luck! =)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but when i try to use -A, to specify jpeg, png it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: @Niko how are you issuing the command? it should be something like `$ wget  -A jpg -F -i <html_file>`. I've not tried it tho